# Selección representativa de muestra heterogénea. Usando Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un panda.df en el cual la columna 1 es el ID, en las siguientes tengo grupos y subgrupos. Se trata de como están clasificados los animales taxonómicamente.

Quiero seleccionar una muestra que represente la diversidad real de mi población, el problema es que población es muy heterogénea. Muestro una imagen de la distribución

[image: sadasdasdasdads]

En el eje X los filos de mi población y en el Y el número de bacterias por filo. (Veasé la escala logarítmica.)

Y aqui muestro la tabla:

```
accession   phylum  class   genus
0   RS_GCF_001999625.1  p__Firmicutes   c__Bacilli  f__Enterococcaceae
1   RS_GCF_001658645.1  p__Firmicutes   c__Bacilli  f__Staphylococcaceae
2   RS_GCF_900117665.1  p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  f__Moraxellaceae
3   RS_GCF_000652055.1  p__Actinobacteriota c__Actinobacteria   f__Mycobacteriaceae
4   RS_GCF_003037025.1  p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  f__Enterobacteriaceae
... ... ... ... ...
143507  GB_GCA_002397995.1  p__Synergistota c__Synergistia  f__Aminobacteriaceae
143508  GB_GCA_002364325.1  p__Bacteroidota c__Bacteroidia  f__Flavobacteriaceae
143509  GB_GCA_002708205.1  p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  f__HTCC2089
143510  GB_GCA_002484035.1  p__Proteobacteria   c__Gammaproteobacteria  f__Pseudomonadaceae
143511  GB_GCA_002725515.1  p__Chloroflexota    c__Dehalococcoidia  f__UBA2963
```

Hay alguna forma de afrontar esto. Si realizo un `random.sample()`, me seleccionan muchas bacterias de los grupos más numerosos y los grupos con pocos representantes no los seleccionan.

Comment: Bienvenido Manuel Dominguez Becerra a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Una muestra de la población seguramente puede llegar a no tener algún "filo", eso dependerá del tamaño de la muestra y de la probabilidad de cada "filo".  ¿Que es lo que consideras, sería una muestra representativa?